# How to control Argo(helm) flow with Script output

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argoproj

I have a script defined in [Argo](https://argoproj.github.io/cd/) `WorkflowTemplate` as follows. This may either print `status:true` or `status:false` (I have simplified this)

```
- name:util-script
    script:
      image: python3
      command: ["python3"]
      script |
         print(status:true)
```

Is there a way to control dag flow based on the above script output? I know helm provides flow control like [Helm Doc - Flow control](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

Following is what I tried so far, but this always jumps to `else` condition. anything Im doing wrong? Appreciate any input on this

```
{{- if contains "status:true" `tasks.util-script.outputs.result` }}
  # even result is `status:true`, does not reach here
{{ else }}
  # always reach here
{{ end }}
```

I have verified `tasks.util-script.outputs.result` indeed returns the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm executes before the workflow runs. That's why you'd end up in the else block.

1. Your task is not evaluated
2. When template is rendered,

   ```
   `tasks.util-script.outputs.result`
   ```

   creates a literal string, which doesn't contain status text

You need to use a `when` conditional, as shown in the documentation - https://argo-workflows.readthedocs.io/en/stable/walk-through/conditionals/

```
- name: next
  template: next
  when: {{`{{tasks.util-script.outputs.result}}`}} == "status:true"
```